# Is there a naming convention to distinguish scalar and vectors?

Tags: matlab, naming-conventions

I've found naming conventions to distinguish vectors and matrices, but not scalars and vectors which I feel will be quite useful to have. I would try to think of my own but I thought it would help to first ask for already existing conventions, because typically these would be better than ones I come up with myself.

Answer (score 4):

Those sort of naming conventions are a bad idea.

If you need to enforce something about the size of your variables, actually enforce it using `assert` or some other mechanism. A naming convention like this will do nothing except to uglify your code and potentially mislead you into a false sense of security.

Instead, name your variables carefully according to the role they play in the code.

BTW, the above is nothing to do with MATLAB: just general good practice in any language.

Comment: I think it'll help, in matlab sometimes I have a variable called pvalue for example, and I forget whether it is a scalar or vector, sometimes it is easy to check but other times when I'm deep into a function or into many functions it becomes quite tedious. It'll also help with debugging, and making the code easier to read, in my opinion.

Comment: If you’re “deep” into a function, that’s already a bad sign. Make your functions short and do one thing only. Keep refactoring until you get to that point. Name your functions and variables clearly, and add documentation comments. Then the purpose of the variable within the code will be clear.

Answer (score 1):

The conventions [here](https://www.ee.columbia.edu/~marios/matlab/MatlabStyle1p5.pdf) seem to be widespread (most google top 10 results for "Matlab naming conventions" return it in some form), and it doesn't contain anything specific about distinguishing variable types.

But as described in the document, variables are usually named `lowercaseWithCapitalizedWords`. Further, it explains that rather than using the same name both singular and plural (E.g. `point` and `points`), one should rather end the plural with `Array` (E.g. `pointArray`)

In that spirit, you could just end your names with  `Vector` or `Scalar`. E.g `nBananasInTreeVector`. That would follow the existing conventions as close as it gets and is intuitive (at least to me). But as Sam Roberts said, if you are at the point where you can't remember your variable type anymore it's probably time to break your code into smaller functions.

Answer (score 1):

Googling a little bit around, you will discover that a few communities, universities, etc... defined their own guidelines for variable naming conventions, but no golden standard has been determined yet.

I don't like the Java `camel case` notation (for example `myVariable`). I prefer to use `lower case` variable names in which every chunk is separated by an underscore (for example `my_variable`).

For what concerns your question... I never felt the need to distinguish between vectors and matrices in a high-vectorizable language in which dimensions are often handled automatically. But I always thought it was important to distinguish between scalars and non-scalar variables using respectively `singular` and `plural` nouns. For example:

```
values = [1 2 0 5 0 1 1 3];
value = 3;
```

Often, in mathematical notation, I found upper case matrices and lower case scalars and vectors. This could be a good starting point. Anyway, you are a free man in this situation and you can eventually define your own convention if you don't like the existing ones. For example:

```
data_m = [1 2; 3 4]; % _m suffix for matrices
data_v = [1 2 3 4]; % _v suffix for vectors
data_s = 1; % _s suffix for scalars
```

The only important thing is that your convention must respect a few simple criterions. It must be:

- consistently used throughout your whole code
- reproductible
- easy to understand (for you)
- easy to deduce and reproduce (for other people manipulating your code)